# DataGrid: change cell color with converter

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` bound to a `DataView` I create from a `DataTable`. The `DataTable` cells are a custom object (`TableCellDifference`) that have some information I'd like to color code.

Here is the xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedTableView}" Grid.Column="2" 
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

The convert method is actually getting called. What I'm curious about, though, is why it's getting called on `DataRowView` rather than a `DataGridCell`, as declared in the trigger.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dataRow = value as DataRowView;
        if (dataRow == null) return null;

        // why does the cast to DataRowView succeed? It
        // seems like this method should be targeting the cell objects
        foreach (object item in dataRow.Row.ItemArray) 
        {
            var cast = item as TableCellDifference;
            if (cast == null) continue;

            switch(cast.Type)
            {
                case TableCellDifferenceType.Addition:
                    return Brushes.LightGreen;

                case TableCellDifferenceType.Mismatch:
                case TableCellDifferenceType.Omission:
                    return Brushes.Red;

                default:
                    return Brushes.White;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

Converter will take the value coming as a result of Binding. As you are using `DataView` as your `ItemsSource`, and `DataView` is comprised of `DataRowView` objects. So, you are getting `DataRowView` as source in your Converter.

Answer (score -1):

The converter name is too much generic and can be a problem. Instead use "CellStyleConverter" as name for example.

Comment: Shouldn't the converter be targeting the cells? It seems to be targeting the  rows and I'm not sure why this is the expected behavior.

Comment: `Convert` is also an interface method of `IValueConverter`; the class name is more specific.

Comment: I wasn´t saying that naming was the problem. @AnjumSKhan answer is correct. I only was saying that correct naming is better in legibility terms.